# PHP maths in foreach loop dynamic updating

Tags: php, math

I'm having trouble doing simple maths (that will get more complicated) in a dynamic table. 
Every time i submit the results, it should add up and store the total score in the $players[$player]['score'] however once its cycled once it resets to zero again.
Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

```
    $new_players = $_SESSION["players"]; 
    //$_SESSION["players"] - brings in array an array like following 

    /* array (size=1)
      'John' => 
        array (size=3)
          'previous' => int 0
          'score' => int 0
          'hand' => int 0  */

    if (empty($players)) {//added as i thought $new_players = $_SESSION["players"]; might be blanking scores
        $players = $new_players;
    } 

if (isset($_POST[$submit])) {
    $new_array = $_POST['player'];
     foreach ($players as $player =>$i) {
        $players[$player]['hand'] = $new_array[$player]+0;//add to convert the $new_array[$player] to int
        $players[$player]['previous'] = $players[$player]['hand'];
        $players[$player]['score'] = $players[$player]['score'] + $players[$player]['hand'];
      }
  }
    ?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" class="formAcc">
    <ul style= "text-align: center">

    <article>
    <li>
    <label>Current Standing</label>
    <?php
      echo '<table id="db_results">
      <colgroup>
        <col class="col15" />
        <col class="col15" />
        <col class="col15" />
        <col class="col15" />
      </colgroup>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Previous Score</th>
    <th>Current Score</th>
    <th>Hand</th>
    </tr>';

    foreach ($players as $player =>$i) {
        echo "<tr class=\"center\">
            <td>". $player . "</td>
            <td>". $i['previous'] . "</td>
            <td>". $i['score'] . "</td>"
            . '<td><input type="text" name="player['.$player.']" value="0"/></td>
            </tr>';
            }
    echo "</table>"; 
    ?>            

<input type="submit" name="<?php echo $submit?>" value="Input Scores" style="margin-top: 5px;"/>

            </li>
        </article>

        </ul>
    </form>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `cycled` ?

Comment: @saibbyweb i just mean once i hit submit button. The results display in the table. Then i enter new input and only the new input is in the total

Comment: what is the value of `$submit` ?

Comment: Simply 'add_scores'

Comment: Why are you looping through players on form submit? Don't you just need to add one more item to the players array?

Comment: Are you starting session by session_start()?

Comment: @PaulMans Hi, Paul yes. Its starts in the header. The problem i basically wasn't resaving the array back to $_SESSION['players'] = $players; as spotted by saibbyweb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving the changes to the `$_SESSION` variable when submit is clicked, try this for submit click handler :

```
if (isset($_POST[$submit])) {
    $new_array = $_POST['player'];
     foreach ($players as $player =>$i) {
        $players[$player]['hand'] = $new_array[$player]+0;//add to convert the $new_array[$player] to int
        $players[$player]['previous'] = $players[$player]['hand'];
        $players[$player]['score'] = $players[$player]['score'] + $players[$player]['hand'];
      }
      /* overwrite $_SESSION['players'] */
      $_SESSION['players'] = $players;
  }
```

Comment: I think you have hit the nail on the head they're @saibbyweb. So simple yes I missed it I will try it as soon as I get home thank you :-)